# Creating an array of strings dynamically in C

Tags: c, string, multidimensional-array, memory-management

I have the next C code on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
#define ID_LEN 5

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int variableNumberOfElements = 5;
    char **orderedIds;

    *orderedIds = (char *) malloc(variableNumberOfElements * sizeof (char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < variableNumberOfElements; i++)
        orderedIds[i] = (char *) malloc((ID_LEN+1) * sizeof(char));


    for (int i = 0; i < variableNumberOfElements; i++)
        free (orderedIds[i]);

    free(*orderedIds);
    return 0;
}
```

I build this code in this way:

```
g++ -g mymain.c
```

when I run this program I receive a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error in line

```
*orderedIds = (char *) malloc(variableNumberOfElements * sizeof (char*));
```

Which is the problem?

UPDATE:

The correct way to allocate memory is:
    orderedIds = (char **) malloc(variableNumberOfElements * sizeof (char*));

and:
    free(orderedIds);

Thanks

Comment: `orderedIds` is uninitialized.

Comment: `orderedIds` is a pointer, but you never make it point anywhere before you derefernece it, leading to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). *Don't* dereference it there (of when calling `free`).

Comment: And in C you [should not cast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

Comment: Looks more like the fault is casting the result of `malloc` to `char *`

Comment: Thanks everybody.  @Someprogrammerdude The compiler needs -fpermissive flag to avoid casting in malloc

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude And there you hve the perfect example why it makes sense to cast malloc: because the code becomes valid C *and* valid  C++. (Perhaps I should add in this case: *Syntactically* correct.)

Comment: @J19 Not if you're really programming in C. Which you say you do in many places. Despite some common syntax, C and C++ are two *very* different languages. The need to cast `malloc` in C++ but not in C is just *one* tiny difference.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude And since you reverted the language tag: the code as presented is (syntactically) correct C and correct C++ (and *semantically* equally incorrect C and C++) but is compiled with a C++ compiler, which makes it -- for people like ligtnessracestoorbit who insists that a program be either C *or* C++ but not both -- a C++ question. (I'd actually be happy with *both* language tags because the question is really valid for both.)

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Actually the use of `g++` to build the code should not automatically make it C++ code. The `g++` frontend program is smart enough to know if it compiles C or C++ code (if it could be called "smart" by just checking the filename extension). The only real difference between `gcc` and `g++` (as you should know) is that `g++` links with the C++ standard library automatically while `gcc` does not. And in C++ I would argue that `malloc` (and friends) is always wrong anyway.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude g++ invokes cc1plus; the "real difference" goes beyond the link state (as you should know ;-) ). The stricter C++ type checking made the malloc cast necessary, according to the comments. Also, it's a side discussion: Pick the compiler of your choice; my argument is that passing compilation with a conformant C++ compiler qualifies code as C++, so the tag is not wrong. That program is *both* valid C and C++ because it is restricted to their common syntactic *and semantic* subset. Consequently it has identical semantical problems in both languages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the time you do this:

```
*orderedIds = (char *) malloc(variableNumberOfElements * sizeof (char*));
```

`orderedIds` is not initialized, so its value is **indeterminite**.   You then attept to dereference this indeterminate value.  Doing so invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You want to assign to `orderedIds` directly:

```
orderedIds = malloc(variableNumberOfElements * sizeof (char*));
```

Then you can further assigned malloc'ed memory to elements of the array you allocated.

You have a similar problem with `free`:

```
free(*orderedIds);
```

`*orderedIds` is the same as `orderedIds[0]` which you've already free'ed, so this is a double free.  This also invokes undefined behavior.  You should instead have:

```
free(orderedIds);
```

Comment: Thank you! Because I don't have -fpermissive enabled, I need to do the casting. For this reason I found the bug. Now I do the correct casting

Comment: @J19 The cast isn't necessary.  If it is then you're compiling as C++, not C.   `-fpermissive` is a C++ option.  Use `gcc` instead.

Comment: @dbush Yes, the OP is compiling with g++, as he mentions in the question. And why should he compile with gcc? C's type checks are much to permissive; for example, you can simply assign void pointers to differently typed variables without giving it a second thought which appears wrong to me.